# Spark Streaming Kafka job stuck in 'processing' stage

Tags: multithreading, jvm, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a streaming job that reads from Kafka (@1min batch) and after some operations POSTs it to a HTTP endpoint. Every few hours it's getting stuck in 'processing' stage and starts queueing jobs thereafter:

[image]

After examining the running 'Executors' (in app-UI page) I found that only 
1 out of 6 executors was showing 2 'Active Tasks'.

[image]

Upon doing thread dump for that, it showed 2 threads for "Executor task launch worker" threadpool ([source](https://github.com/ueshin/apache-spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/executor/Executor.scala#L85)). These threads were all stuck at the same error:

[image]

Full readable error:

```
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
java.net.InetAddress.checkLookupTable(InetAddress.java:1393)
java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1310)
java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276)
java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1076)
java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(InetSocketAddress.java:220)
kafka.network.BlockingChannel.liftedTree1$1(BlockingChannel.scala:59)
kafka.network.BlockingChannel.connect(BlockingChannel.scala:49)
kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.connect(SimpleConsumer.scala:44)
kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.getOrMakeConnection(SimpleConsumer.scala:151)
kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.liftedTree1$1(SimpleConsumer.scala:69)
kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.kafka$consumer$SimpleConsumer$$sendRequest(SimpleConsumer.scala:68)
kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(SimpleConsumer.scala:112)
kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:112)
kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:112)
kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:33)
kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1.apply$mcV$sp(SimpleConsumer.scala:111)
kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:111)
kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:111)
kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:33)
kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.fetch(SimpleConsumer.scala:110)
org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.fetchBatch(KafkaRDD.scala:193)
org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.getNext(KafkaRDD.scala:209)
org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:461)
scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.UnsafeShuffleWriter.write(UnsafeShuffleWriter.java:161)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This seems to be a [JDK bug](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=7012768) that must have been fixed in JDK 7 - I made sure that I am using '1.8.0_101 (Oracle Corporation)'. I tried adding following on the command line (as suggested [here](https://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Configuring_for_IPv4)), but it didn't fix the issue:

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dnetworkaddress.cache.ttl=60
```

Does anyone have any ideas on an approach to debug/fix this?

*Edit: Renaming the question to remove confusing JDK reason

Comment: It hangs on a host name resolution. Take a heapdump to see what name it tries to resolve. You may also try alternative Java DNS client by adding the following option: `-Dsun.net.spi.nameservice.provider.1=dns,sun`

Comment: It gets stuck at resolving kafka broker hosts. Interestingly it doesn't fail always, once every couple of hours.

Comment: some time host resolution takes more time that depends on DNS of your cloud provider 

I faced the same problem as i was using InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("www.example.com") , so I  put timeout on Http connection  and used another service for DNS lookup 


also ip based configuration all across the cluster and putting private ip  helps in smooth running of cluster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be a kernel-level bug https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1209433 which is resolved in linux kernel version 4.0.6 and the hosts where my workers are running they have RHEL with kernel version 3.5.6. Hopefully after deploying on newer CentOS machines with kernel version 4.5 it won't be an issue.

How I figured it out is every time it gets stuck at 'checkLookupTable' or 'lookupAllHostAddr', both are native (JNI) calls to underlying OS.